# Weird function seems to change vector values

Tags: c++, vector, return

I have to program something that filters email by checking if the source of the email is found in a blacklist or if any word in the email's content is found in a list of blocked words.

Here's the function that filters the email.

```
void filterEmail(vector<email>& amis, vector<email>& corbeille, 
                 vector<email>& rejete, vector<email>& emails, 
                 vector<string> b, vector<string> w, 
                 vector<string> spam)
    {
        bool isListed(email, vector<string>);
        bool isSpam(email, vector<string>);

        for(vector<email>::size_type i = 0; i < emails.size();)
        {
            if(isListed(emails[i], b))
            {
                corbeille.push_back(emails[i]);
                emails.erase(emails.begin() + i); 
            }
            else i++;
        }
        for(vector<email>::size_type i = 0; i < emails.size();)
        {
            if(isListed(emails[i], w))
            {
                amis.push_back(emails[i]); 
                emails.erase(emails.begin() + i);
            }
            else i++;
        }
        for(vector<email>::size_type i = 0; i < emails.size();)
        {
            if(isSpam(emails[i], spam))
            {
                cout << emails[i].source << "   " << emails[i].content[0]; 
                rejete.push_back(emails[i]); 
                emails.erase(emails.begin() + i);
            }
            else i++;
        }

        return;
    }
```

I have a really weird problem with the part where it checks for spam words in the content (3rd for loop)
after a few test cout's I realised after the first time isSpam returns true, the content of the email changes to the line where it first returns true, and all the next emails return true.

```
bool isSpam(const email e, const vector<string> motsinterdis)
{
    for(vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < e.content.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(vector<string>::size_type j = 0; j < motsinterdis.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(string::npos != e.content[i].find(motsinterdis[j]))
            {
                cout << e.source << endl;
                cout << motsinterdis[j] << " found in " << e.content[i] << endl;

                return true;

            }
        }
    }

return false;
}
```

I have an Struct Email, which contains a vector content. Sorry for the french variables in there :P
Hope I've been clear enough,
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should really be using iterators for most of the vector loops. `size_type` and `++i` will work, but isn't as idiomatic, and the compiler may not be able to get as clever (it's also less likely to give you early errors on an overrun).

Comment: I was using iterators but had a lot of problems with erases where I'd get a  not dereferencable error, after reading some questions here the solution seemed to be using size_type..

Comment: size_type will also give you problems, just no error (it's prone to skipping an item, but won't give the invalid iterator that you get otherwise). Those are precisely the sort of errors that make iterators better, the compiler or runtime can warn you when the item becomes invalid. There are also work-arounds to avoid leaving yourself with an invalid iterator (I remember some language returning a new, valid iterator pointing to the next element, not sure if it was C++).

Comment: Hmm I see. I'll see if I can find a way to make iterator work.. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have a similar problem right now too. I switched to size_type after that. Please share your knowledge if you get iterators work.

Comment: I switched everything to iterators, I commented out the erase for now, but i still get the same problem. Every email after the first one that contains a spam word is added to the spam list. It's like some part of my code changes the content of all my content vector...

Comment: Pass the content vector as constant reference or use const_iterators, then see what the compiler complains about.  This will give you good starting place to debug.

Comment: There are still missing pieces (e.g. the `email` class and the `isListed` function). And is this code *minimal*? That is, can you remove any part of it and still reproduce the error?